# What is a simple but somewhat effective way to "obfuscate" numeric values?

Tags: c#, algorithm, ms-access, encryption

Let's say I have an Access database table that has 2 columns: one is ID (from 1 to 20000, sequentially and each is unique) and one is Value (any number from 0 to 500).

How do I obfuscate the Value field (using ID or not using ID) in a ***simple*** but somewhat effective way? I expect something slightly more effective than ROT13 obfuscation but not so complicated that decoing needs more than one line of code. The decoding is done in C# code. The obfuscation is done via calculated field in Access.

I changed the "encryption" to "obfuscation" to reflect the simplicity of the goal which is NOT to prevent "attack" but only to avoid careless exposure of data.

Comment: How would you define "somewhat effective"? Would you consider XOR-ing somewhat effective?

Comment: @biziclop This is, as you already notice, very subjective. For me, just add 1 to each Value is not effective. However, add the last 2 digits of the ID to Value is somewhat effective. I want to find out if there is any elegant way of doing this.

Comment: For that matter value+1 could be "somewhat effective"

Comment: It might help if you tell us what you are going to be using the encrypted values for. The answer may change depending on that response.

Comment: ROT13 is obfuscation, not encryption.  It sounds like that's what you're really looking for - is this true?

Comment: Obfuscation is a better word. When I looked at ROT13 at wikipedia, I didn't see 'obfuscation' so didn't know to use it.

Comment: You are asking a question about a security technique **without describing the threat, the attacker, the vulnerability or the resource being protected**. In order to get a sensible answer to the question you need to tell us what attack the proposed mechanism is supposed to defend against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what is your goal/attacker profile?  If your requirement is anything more than stopping casual viewing you have imposible requirements... if you only care about stopping casual viewing (which is better termed obfuscation than encryption) you could try something like

`b = a % 7 == 0 ? ((a/7)*991) : a % 2 == 0 ? ((a/2)*787) : a * 317`

and on the other end

`b = a % 991 == 0 ? ((a/991)*7) : a % 787 == 0 ? ((a/787)*2) : a/317`

Note that this is very weak but your requirements exclude any useful form of encryption.

Comment: How did you choose the numbers 991, 787, 317, etc.? Thanks.

Comment: they are primes so that are out of your allowed range.  I chose them this way so that you wouldn't inadvertently end up with a number that was divisible by one of them... they are also large enough that many people won't see the pattern immediately.

Comment: Thank you, this is first practical formula I could find. The only answers I got so far were "why do you need that" and "it is nonsense anyway". I found [way to obfuscate string values on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38130563/2392157) usable also for numbers, but your answer allows to obfuscate numbers as numbers.  +1

Answer (score 7):

For a number from 0 to 500, encryption is essentially useless.

First, the length is too short to effectively encrypt using normal means such as XOR. Once you know the value of one value, you can likely re-create the key to decrypt others. Encryption works best when you're working with a large original piece of data.

Second, if the data is available to a user in Access, the encryption algorithm will be too, at least to a determined person. If they can see the calculation used to encrypt the value, they can probably create their own decryption algorithm.

Third, with only 501 possible values, the value is highly prone to a dictionary attack -- i.e., someone just guessing each value, and they'll on average only have to guess 250 times. That's fewer than even a simple 3-digit lock on a briefcase. So, encrypting probably won't do you much good.