# Safest way to use SQL Connection Strings in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, string, connection

I'm creating a program in VB.Net that heavily interacts with 2 large MSSQL databases.  I do not know a ton of vb and I'm fairly new, but I would assume just having the connection strings in the code and releasing the program it would be quite easy for someone to reverse the program and get my connection info? correct me if I'm wrong.

My question is I'm wondering if there is a safer way to use a connection string in my program.  Would I just have to encrypt my app? Create a module or dll?

Comment: Please read this Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727089/what-is-a-simple-but-somewhat-effective-way-to-obfuscate-numeric-values#comment12369072_9727089

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt just the portions of the .config file which contain the sensitive material, in this case connection strings.

The answer is aspnet_regiis.exe

The location may vary depending on your system and version of .NET, but a file search should narrow it down.

Let's say you have a program called myapp located in c:\dotnetaps\myapp.

I use the following command to encrypt the "connectionStrings" portion of web.config:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef connectionStrings C:\dotnetapps\myapp
```

Wait a second: web.config is only for web apps, not local ones, right?
aspnet_regiis.exe only works for web.config, but *the format is exactly the same as app.config*. Therefore, all you need to do is rename app.config to web.config, run the tool, and rename it back. A little awkward, but nothing that can't be automated by a batch file.

```
@ Encrypts connectionStrings in app.config
ren C:\dotnetapps\myapp\app.config web.config
path\to\exe\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef connectionStrings C:\dotnetapps\myapp
ren web.config app.config
```

Important note: Using literally these commands will encrypt the file against the particular system it is running on. You'll want to do a little reading to get it to encrypt against a key that allows you to distribute your code, but this is the general idea.

Comment: I am not currently using ASP.Net.  I am creating a windows based environment program in Visual Basic .Net 2010

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that shouldn't matter -- just a matter of getting the executable, perhaps by installing IIS Express or similar. I'm not sure exactly what Visual Studio or IIS program includes aspnet_regiis.exe, but I'd just think of it as another installation like any other tool. It should still work for your program. You'll just need to put your connection strings in app.config. See the following example: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1145.htm

Answer (score -1):

You could store it in your resources file (MyFile.resx) as an encrypted string.