# Obfuscate decimal(6,2) number using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, decimal, obfuscation, deobfuscation

How can I effectively obfuscate numbers from range 0.00 ~ 9999.99 like

- 11.68
- 6.84
- 7.99
- 7.00

so that small difference in values of similarily-sized numbers is not immediately visible?

I thought about splitting each number into integer and decimal part and use them as coordinates (e.g. `11.68 → (11, 68)`) and converting them to polar coords, which is nice, but I still need two values to store them.

**Do you know some nice tranformation of decimal(6,2) into another single number (can be like `float` or even `int`) and back which relies only on [T-SQL math functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177516.aspx)?**

---

I would like to add one more barrier between values and people who have full database acceess and can be tempted to analyze true (unobfuscated) values they see, but are relatively lazy to learn T-SQL and study how "nonsense values" they see after obfuscation, can be decoded.

Comment: You should give an example of suitable "obfuscation" here. Do you mean randomly fudging them?

Comment: @tadman – yes I mean something in what human brain cannot easily find a pattern even when in possible range 0~9999 most values are around 6, 7, 8.  So even semi-random distribution is fine until it can be decoded back to original decimal(6,2) number.

Comment: If you're adding obfuscation of this sort to prevent some kind of "decoding" when people get into your database, you're fighting a battle you can't win. Secure your data. Do not let people close to it. If someone gets their hands on the mangled data and the application you've made to decode it, you've done all this work for nothing, it can be undone with a line of code. This is a fool's errand. Hackers aren't lazy. They're exceptionally persistent.

Comment: @tadman – I fully understand your point and I'm thinking the same, but well, in this case, this is not a corporate environment, where everything can be kept under proper roles and responsibilities. If someone can leave for a while b/w thinking "why do you need this" and come up with interesting math function, I will be thankful. Even if I won't use it, then at least to see how such functions can be constructed.

Comment: There's a high probability that this code will cause problems later on that will be extremely difficult to track down. What if this introduces a small amount of error into the values that nobody notices until it's too late? Use raw values. If you need encryption, which could be a concern, encrypt things using a proper cryptographic method, not some home-rolled obfuscator.

Comment: @tadman – I think there is not much difference between obfuscation and encryption if both start and end at the SQL level. (And I need to stay at SQL level.)

Comment: There's an enormous difference between encryption and obfuscation. Encryption can be made secure, it's also generally done with a well-known, proven algorithm. It's a trusted method for securing data. Obfuscation is often a nuisance and no obstacle to anyone determined to defeat it. If your application needs the numbers, it will have to decode them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116118/discussion-between-miroxlav-and-tadman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE() and DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()

Suitable methods are already present since SQL Server 2008. Their purpose is encryption, but well, with locally stored passphrase it's merely just an obfuscation :) (Anyway, at the moment this is what was expected in the question.)

```sql
DECLARE @Value decimal(6,2) = 7.99;
DECLARE @Passphrase varchar(4) = 'abcd';

-- obfuscation
DECLARE @Obf varbinary(50) = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@Passphrase, CAST(@Value AS varchar(20)));

-- deobfuscation
SELECT CAST(CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@Passphrase, @Obf) AS varchar(20)) AS decimal(6,2))
```

Value obfuscated this way can be also held in `varchar`/`nvarchar` data type.